# installation freezes in kubuntu 15.10 on aspire laptop

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, live-usb, laptop, acer

I am trying to install kubuntu 15.10 (from an USB stick) on an Acer Aspire R3-471T laptop with win10. Problem is: I get to the install screen where I can put in the name of the system as well as choose the language but when I click on "continue" the mouse pointer turns into a waiting symbol and thats it ... nothing else happens. I can still minimize the window though... any idea what is going on here? It would also be cool to get a hint how to find out what is going wrong here.

(I have successfully used the exact same USB stick with the exact same install disk on other systems)

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with the kubuntu logo, during boot, hit `e` on grub screen (when you turn your computer on).
Then, remove the `quiet` and `splash` options at the end of the second line. Hit F10 to boot.

If it doesn't work, you will have error messages displayed.